# Puppeteer: how to manage time like a fake timers in Jasmine do?

Tags: puppeteer

I need to manage time in browser like a fake timers in Jasmine do to avoid long waiting for test results in real time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Lolex](https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex), an implementation of fake JavaScript timers.

First, add the Lolex library to the page using [`page.addScriptTag()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageaddscripttagoptions).

Next, begin using Lolex in the Page DOM environment using [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

```
await page.addScriptTag( {
    'url' : 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lolex@2.7.1/src/lolex-src.min.js'
});

await page.evaluate( () =>
{
    const clock = lolex.createClock();

    clock.setTimeout( () =>
    {
        console.log( 'Hello, world!' );

    }, 500 );

    clock.tick( 500 );
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Except that my browser environment couldn't handle the esmodule syntax, so I had to use `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lolex@2.7.1/lolex.min.js` instead of the url in the answer.